# Serving blobstore images through SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, blobstore

After adding SSL for our domain, I started seeing these kind of warnings:

```
The page at 'https://www.mydomain.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://lh6.ggpht.com/SfTsfy6g-LC2F_GNdiw12s8agFUjcTPB1AzCJon-dIfTG1zaKGHH9tk6be--gOIg-ubWoFuTAbdlo': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

What is the best way to serve those images through SSL aswell. Currently I have a lot of Jinja2 templates referring to the images like this:

`{{blobstore_image}}`

I can simply replace http with https like this:

`{{blobstore_image|replace('http', 'https'}}`

But is there a way to always return https links from a Serve Handler's `send_blob()` instead ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just strip the `http:` part from the link and it will automatically serve the link with the protocol your page is serving.

so the link would look like this:

`//www.yourdomain.com/foobar`

Comment: Yeah, that should be better than replacing it. Thanks! I was just wondering if there is a way of doing that automatically as `send_blob()` always returns it with `http`.

Comment: don't think thats possible. but you could do it before sending the variable to the template

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `secure_url=True` if you are serving the image using the `get_serving_url()` method:

```
from google.appengine.api import images

image_serving_url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key, secure_url=True)
```

This will return a serving URL with the SSL.

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images#Image_get_serving_url

Comment: Thanks! Seems this has been added after my initial post of the question.